# Get the values from CW column to CA column: "End of List" Message at the first blank merged row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to get the values from CW column to CA column. (It is a printable table structure starting from CA4 to CA36.)

CA column has merged cells (4 cells) from CA4, CA8, CA12, CA16...CA36

CA4 =IF(BW="","",BW4) draggable till CA36

At the first blank cell, I get

> End of List

I tried this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($CA$3:$CA7,"End of List")>0,"",IFERROR(INDEX($BW$4:$BW$1000,SMALL(IF($BW$4:$BW$1000<>"",ROW($BW$4:$BW$1000),""),ROWS($CA$4:$CA8))-ROW($CA$3)),"End of List"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=LET(lst,FILTER(BW:BW,BW:BW<>""),num,COUNTA(lst),indx,ROW()/4,
          IF(indx<=num,INDEX(lst,indx,1),IF(indx=num+1,"End of list","")))
```

My test:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked,  your solutions, ENDS my problem. :)